# 8bit Quantization of Conv2D Transposed Layers

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, quantization

I am trying to wrap my head around quantized Conv2D Transposed and their relation to a regular quantized Conv2D operation. We can rewrite the transposed version of the layer by dilating the input with zeros and setting the stride to 1. This brings me to my questions:

1. If the quantized Conv2D Transposed Operation has an input zero point other than zero, do I have to dilate with that value, or do I still use zero for the dilation?
2. When we quantize a Conv2d Transposed layer, I noticed that TFLite adds a Requantize operator to the output of the computation. I know that for the regular convolution, this can be computed by adjusting the bias and scaling the result of the computation. Is this different for the transposed version?

For some background, I want to import the quantized model into TVM and then further process it there. My issue is that the results do not match between the TVM and the TFLite version.